# how to store object to NSmutablearray in app delegate?

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray

I'm having a problem with storing and accessing objects with NSmutable array in app delegate. I have tried methods form other websites and stack overlay pages but yet no solution. I want to able to access the array data in another view. Currently nothing is working for me.

Heres my code.

```
AppDelegate.h :


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray* sharedArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSMutableArray* sharedArray;


ViewController.h :


#import "AppDelegate.h"

-(void)viewDidLoad{

 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            NSMutableArray *model = appDelegate.sharedArray;

            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [dict setObject:@"hello" forKey:@"title"];

            [dict setObject:@"urlhere" forKey:@"thumbnail"];


            [model addObject:dict];


            NSLog(@"submitted to array: %@",model);

}
```

Comment: My guess is that you never create the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you, at any point, initializing the `sharedArray`? The array must be instantiated before you can add objects to it. For example:

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.sharedArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    return YES;
}
```

Having done that, now attempts to add objects to this array from your view controllers should succeed.

---

Unrelated, but you should *not* define instance variables for your properties. Let the compiler synthesize that for you, e.g.:

AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
// {
//     NSMutableArray* sharedArray;
// }

@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSMutableArray* sharedArray;

@end
```

What you have is technically acceptable, but it's inadvisable because of possible confusion between this `sharedArray` instance variable and the what the compiler will synthesize for you (e.g. if you don't have a `@synthesize` line, the compiler will automatically create an instance variable called `_sharedArray`, with a leading underscore, for you). Even if you had a `@synthesize` line that ensured that the instance variable was correct, having the explicitly declared instance variable is simply redundant.

Comment: So in app delegate i only add     self.sharedArray = [NSMutableArray array];     is that right?

Comment: @AlexH -- No, you *understand why you should* add that statement or it's equivalent.  Then do what you should do.